# Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error

Tags: laravel

Recently I use PHP version 8.1 and create a Laravel project by using composer as follows:

> composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app 4.2 --prefer-dist

However, I get the following error though I search in the internet many times I cannot get the answer.

> php artisan clear-compiled

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

> Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1

I am just a beginner of PHP and Laravel. Please help.

BR,
Terry

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are installing an old version of Laravel (4.2), since the `mcrypt` extension is not required anymore and [removed from Laravel in 5.1](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9041).

Since you are using PHP 8.1, I suppose you just want to install Laravel's latest version, like this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app
```

The installation documentation for Laravel 10.x can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation).